# Multiple Subdomains, Multiple (v)Servers, single IPv4

Tags: apache, proxy, subdomain, reverse-proxy, ip-address

I have a problem.

I want do have serval subdomains for different servers. But I have only one (1) IP-Address. I want to have one subdomain per server, if possible. And I sm not only using port 80/443, port 3389 or 22 too ;-).

I have allready looked for an Apache VirtualHost config template for my problem, but after some endless hours I had no success at all.

A concept I want to realize:
sub1.domain.tld -> LAN-Address 10.0.0.10
sub2.domain.tld -> LAN-Address 10.0.0.11
…

Can someone help me out of this problem?

OS: Windows and/or Linux
Network (LAN): nothing special so far (private network in Germany)
There are no limitations on how many (v)servers I use.

If you need more informations, feel free to ask.

Thank you

Comment: Configure one server to receive all traffic. Configure a `<VirtualHost>` for each subdomain. Add `<ProxyPass>` to each VirtulHost for the subdomain that you want to forward traffic to another server. However, that will not help you forward traffic for ports 3389 or 22. You will need to configure a **jump host** to get onto the other systems.

Comment: Hello BillThor,

Thank You for your informations.

Creating certificates with (all) subdomains used for the proxy is no problem.
I can do it :-)

The problem I get is how to do a proxyserver for it.
I read I can use an apache webserver operating as a proxy for it.
But by now I found wheter a good describing forum post or a script for doing this.
So, if you can provide me one of these both options I would be very pleased for this.

Greetings
Robert

PS: are there any other ideas how to maybe proxy ssh/rdp?

Comment: I suggest to use `nginx`: https://timothy-quinn.com/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-sites/. For proxying tcp with `nginx`see: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: The SSH protocol cannot be proxied. You can either tunnel SSH inside HTTP or create a jump host. I am not sure if RDP can be proxied, but it can be tunneled.

Comment: Thank you for the informations. How can I tunnel the rdp? And with nginx are there also virtualhosts? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this in Apache2 server is by creating multiple conf files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Since I have multiple subdomains and multiple ports, I am generating the `.conf` files automatically based on a template.

The full script is:

```
#! /bin/bash

template_file="subdomain-template"

for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 20)
do

    subdomain="sandbox${i}"
    newfile="${subdomain}.conf"
    port="9${i}"
    
    sed "s/subdomainname/$subdomain/g" $template_file > $newfile

done
```

You can see the full script [in this repo](https://github.com/kommetio/bashutils/tree/main/apache2-multiple-subdomains).